# Google Styled Maps Integration in iOS swift app, issue in JSON file

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, google-maps

I am integrating Google Styled Maps via JSON file in my iOS swift App.

What I am doing:
1) I have copied JSON code from of my google map style from mystyle.withgoogle.com
2) Create a new file in XCode named it "style.json" and paste the JSON code in it.
3) Placed the JSON file at the same place where my .swift files are located
4) trying to use it in one of my activity named "History.swift"

but always getting error that "Unable to find style.json"

What Should I do? My code is here as copied from google developer.

```
     do {
            // Set the map style by passing the URL of the local file.
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
                mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: Can you attach the json file?

Comment: And are you sure the file is added in your bundle?

Comment: Go to App Target -> Build Phases and check the Bundle Resource and check if file is there or not, because i checked your code with demo file and it was working just fine.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I didn't at it in my bundle

Comment: that solved my problem its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding json file to my Project's Bundle it's working as expected. Thanks to @Shabbir jan.